# Enable/Disable fullscreen option video.js HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video, fullscreen

How can I enable/disable the fullscreen option of one video from my post tag HTML in Wordpress? I'm using [Video.js](http://www.videojs.com/).

I would not like to make it for ever, just decide which video I want with it or without it, anytime. I tried `AllowFullScreen="true/false"` but it doesn't work.

Comment: [disable](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/v4.3.0/docs/api/vjs.FullscreenToggle.md#disable) or [off](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/v4.3.0/docs/api/vjs.FullscreenToggle.md#off-type-fn-)

Answer (score 13):

Current version of video-js (6.x.x) supports disabling of fullscreen button also by `fullscreenToggle` option. You can simply set it during init of the player like this:

```
videojs("my-video", {
    controlBar: {
      fullscreenToggle: false
    }
});
```

However, I observed that it doesn't mean that you are not able to enter fullscreen by hand gesture on mobile devices. (For example reverse pinch on iPad - two fingers on the screen and moving them apart). That's another story - I'm dealing with it by listening for `fullscreenchange` event and checking `isFullscreen()` state of the player (fullscreenchange event triggers on opening but on closing of the fullscreen as well), if it's in fullscreen then I'm calling `exitFullscreen()` function. Just like this:

```
videojs("my-video",{controlBar: {fullscreenToggle: false}}).ready(function(){
    let myPlayer = this;
    myPlayer.on("fullscreenchange", function(){
        if(myPlayer.isFullscreen()){
            myPlayer.exitFullscreen();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Add class to video as below

```
.vjs-nofull .vjs-fullscreen-control {
    display:none;
}
```

to

```
<video class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-nofull" ....></video>
```

Hope it works

Answer (score 4):

Looking through the video.js documentation, getting the child component named `FullscreenToggle` is a pretty involved process. For me, only `myPlayer.children()[5].children()[7]` did the trick, where `myPlayer` is defined here:

```
videojs("lodestar_video").ready(function(){
    myPlayer = this;
});
```

However, calling `.disable()` and `.disposed()` didn't work and returned `undefined`.

What worked for me was a CSS solution: making sure it doesn't appear using `display:none` and then setting the appropriate margin so the volume control doesn't go out of place.

```
.vjs-fullscreen-control { 
    display: none; 
} 

.vjs-default-skin .vjs-volume-control { 
    margin-right: 20px; 
}
```

The downside of this is the small overhead since the fullscreen button is still created and loaded, only not displayed, but this should be near-negligible in the light of loading an entire video.

Comment: Add !important .vjs-fullscreen-control { 
    display: none !important; 
} 

.vjs-default-skin .vjs-volume-control { 
    margin-right: 20px !important; 
}

Comment: It still allows the fullscreen toggle on a double-click, I presume.

Answer (score 3):

In 7.5.0 you can use this to hide the full-screen button and disable double-click

```
videojs("my-player", {
    controlBar: {
        fullscreenToggle: false
    },
    userActions: {
        doubleClick: false
    }
});
```